# grep two strings but only if the 2nd string is in the next line

Tags: shell, grep

I can grep two strings 'ion' and 'spin' from a file but would also like to either:

- grep only if both strings exist
- or only grep if the 2nd string is in the next line

`grep  -w  'ion\|spin'  filename`

I want to grep from a file which contains random strings like this:

```
  <set comment="ion 3">
   <set comment="spin 1">
```

but only if the word "spin" occurs in the next line.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: I hope you meant to make it so that the upper code is also in a grey box?